Can everybody help me remove glue
Can everybody help me remove glue as following picture.


I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with electrical engineering.

@Hearth Claiming that electronic enclosures have nothing to do with electrical engineering is a strange statement. It might however be a repair question needing more details.

@Lundin if the glue were somehow involved in the electrical/electronic operation of the device, then sure. But claiming that gluing (or un-gluing) things in boxes is EE just because the things in question are electrical is what's strange here.

@brhans Those who have worked with electrical engineering in the real world know that there are both EMC and ESD concerns here. The enclosure, the glue and everything else may or may not be conductive. Enclosures with high EMC requirements need EMC gaskets. There are IP class concerns which is not just about mechanics but also covers electrical safety. Conductivity of things placed near an antenna might also matter. Chassis grounding. Specific absorption rate. And so on.

Lots of word-salad - all of which has nothing whatsoever to do with the OP's question about removing some kind of glue which they almost certainly can't identify. Stop trying to make an electrical engineering question out of something which is clearly not one.

It looks like silicone. One thing that works well is 99% isopropanol. It destroys the bond to the plastic, and is a relatively mild solvent so it doesn't tend to destroy anything else in the process.
Work it in around the edges and let it sit for a while (maybe saturate a cloth with it) - but take care about the flammability.
